# Interfacing standard Gazebo sensors with ROS

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It seems to be a trivial task, but I can't find an answer so far.

I need to interface standard sensors like (camera, laser scanner etc.) with ROS. [This page](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo_plugins) mentions all the plugins I need, but there is no further information on this.

Gazebo Wiki is silent about this as well. The only thing there is how to write your own plugin.

What did I miss?

Thanks,

Boris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/993/interfacing-standard-gazebo-sensors-with-ros/) by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think this is tutorial you're looking for:

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/ros_enabled_model_plugin

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-01-23**:
Although it is helpful, but not exactly what I'm looking for. Is there ready to use plugins like this? Looks like it won't be a problem to write one, but I would prefer to reuse the existing ones. Thanks.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-09-19**:
More current information about using ROS with Gazebo: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins